# sql date difference

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am using oracle 10g

I need to get the difference between two dates in the format of to_char(‘HH24:MI’).

I tried to apply :

```
Select to_char(FRM_TIME-HOURS_IN,'HH24:MI') FROM Time_Test
```

but it gave me invalid number format.

Can you please help.

Comment: **WHAT** database system? SQL is just the structured query language - used by many database systems. Stuff like this is vendor-specific - so we need to know what database system (which **product**) you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I'd use:

```
select to_char(DATE '2000-01-01' + (FRM_TIME-HOURS_IN),'HH24:MI') FROM Time_Test
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use

`datediff()` to get Date diff.

Comment: i tried datediff but still it did'nt work. below is my sample query.
select datediff(HOURS_IN-FRM_Time) from Time_Test

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT HOURS_IN
, FRM_TIME
, (24 * extract(day from (FRM_TIME- HOURS_IN) day(9) to second))
+ extract(hour from (FRM_TIME- HOURS_IN) day(9) to second)
+ ((1/100) * extract(minute from (FRM_TIME- HOURS_IN) day(9) to second)) as "HOUR.MINUTE"
* from t
```